# sqlite drop table c++

Tags: c++, sqlite

where is the problem with the following code? It's can not DROP my table. When I make this drop from sql browser (on the same databade) - all works fine.

```
int rcc = sqlite3_open_v2(str_sessions_file.c_str(), &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL );
if ( SQLITE_OK != rcc)
{
    fprintf (stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg (db));
    sqlite3_close (db);
    return;
}


// Drop 
std::string sql_dropatable = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sessions";   


if( sqlite3_exec(db, sql_dropatable.c_str(), 0, 0, 0) != SQLITE_OK ) { // or == -- same effect
    std::cout << "SQLite can't drop sessions table" << std::endl;
    sqlite3_close (db);
    //exit (1); 
    return; 
}
```

Comment: So why don't you show the error message?

Comment: Does your table still exist?

Comment: @sqlab yes, I add checking for error message and got "Database is Locked" error. There is No journal file. maybe application crashed on same place after sqlite database was open. does not know how to prevent this and why it's still licked while only one process tying to open database.

Comment: Is your browser closed, did you call sqlite3_reset() or sqlite3_finalize() after precedent SELECTs?

Comment: @sqlab i do `while (sqlite3_step) {` no calls to `sqlite3_reset()` or `finalize()` in the loop. need them? } but after `while` on the end of the function I call `finalize()`.

Comment: That seems ok, no need to do that in the loop.

Comment: "Locked" means that *some* connection still has an open transaction, either in this or another process.

Comment: @CL no. in my situation the server shoot down when `SELECT` proccessed but before `close()` or `finalize()` called. so, database is blocked. I need some nice solution to detect this and unlock the database. now I know about `dumb database to new file, then delete old database and move dumbed to existen location` but this is bad solution (not elegant!)

Comment: @sqlab thanks for you comment. please check my last comment. it's what I found for now, but still no elegant solution to unlock.

Comment: Can you confirm that there is no process holding the database open, even a zombie process?